# Equation for splitting a charge between n wires

Tags: ohms-law, kirchhoffs-laws

If I had a 10 amps of current that was split down two wires, one with 1 ohms of resistance and another with 2 ohms of resistance, what equation would I use to determine how much charge went down each wire?

Comment: You are looking for a [current divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_divider).

Comment: The given answer is correct as long as both of your wires actually form a closed circuit (they are not open ended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the resistance ratio between the wires is 2:1 so will be the current. ie 3.3A:6.6A.

Comment: So it's just the ratio between the resistances?

Comment: correct. With the lower resistance taking the larger current. Lookup Kirchoffs Current Law for details. But essentially current into a node (in this case the end of your wires where they meet) must equal the current out. So 10A in must eq 10A out.

Comment: That's awesome.

Comment: If you wish to use an equation. Consider that the circuit you have is basically 2 resistors in parrallel. In a parrallel circuit the voltage applied to the two resistors will be equal. So if you use Ohms law I=V/R then you can work out the actual current. It should be the same values as above.

Comment: @Lurk21  It is not "just ratio between the resistances".  It is ***just*** the equal voltage across the resistances that are connected in parallel.

Comment: @NickAlexeev yes Nick is quite correct. I was being a bit too simplistic.